# Proving that $(A\setminus C)\cap(B\setminus C)\cap(A\setminus B)=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each $A,B,C$ how would I prove that $(A\setminus C)\cap(B\setminus C)\cap(A\setminus B)=\emptyset$ ?

My thoughts are if $x\in (A\setminus C)\cap(B\setminus C)\cap(A\setminus B)$, then $x\in (A\setminus C)$ and $x\in (B\setminus C)$ and $x\in (A\setminus B)$ so $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$ and $x \in B$ and $x \not \in C$  and $x \in A$  and $x \not\in B$.

How would I continue from here?

Comment: indeed, you solved it already!

Comment: Notice that you have both $x \in B$ and $x \notin B$. How many points meet this condition?

Comment: @eigenchris by any chance, do you know why the $A$ looks two times different in the question body or in the title? It's not an optical illusion, is it?!

Comment: @user190080 I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. The $A$'s all look the same to me.

Comment: @eigenchris now everything looks fine. Just before the edit it looked like $(Α\backslash C)\cap(A\backslash B)$...the reason for this is because the "A" was somehow copied from somewhere else so it seems which corrupted the rendering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you have picked up on *the* main issue via avid19's push in the right direction, but I would encourage you to think about associativity of $\cap$, something that would immediately answer the question for you:
\begin{align}
(Α\setminus C)\cap(B\setminus C)\cap(A\setminus B)&= (A\cap C^C)\cap(B\cap C^C)\cap(A\cap B^C)\tag{by defn.}\\[0.5em]
&= A\cap C^C\cap B\cap C^C\cap A\cap B^C\tag{assoc. of $\cap$}\\[0.5em]
&= A\cap A\cap C^C\cap C^C\cap B\cap B^C\tag{assoc. of $\cap$}\\[0.5em]
&= (A\cap A)\cap (C^C\cap C^C)\cap (B\cap B^C)\tag{parens}\\[0.5em]
&= (A\cap C^C)\cap(B\cap B^C)\tag{simplify}\\[0.5em]
&= (A\cap C^C)\cap\varnothing\tag{simplify}\\[0.5em]
&= \varnothing\tag{simplify}.
\end{align}
That was probably what someone had in mind when designing that exercise; that is, the goal was for you to see how to use the associativity of $\cap$ to conclude that you end up with $\text{something}\cap(B\cap B^C)$, where you can immediately see that this reduces to $\varnothing$, the right-hand side.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.One question,how did we get from the 1st line to the 2nd line? For example is true if I do: (A∩B)∩(C∩D)∩(E∩F)=A∩F or =A∩E or =E∩B etc.

Comment: @MarkoPolo You need to be careful with your uses of "or" / "and." One typical exercise is to prove that $A\cap(B\cap C)=(A\cap B)\cap C$. That is, when you encounter an expression where are all of the components are linked together with *only* $\cap$'s...you can move them around however you want. I'll add a step or two to my answer so you can see how this works. And maybe it will make sense then.

Comment: @MarkoPolo You are very welcome! I have updated the answer with some additional intermediate steps for additional clarity. Hopefully it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 8):

You have $x\in B$ and $x\not\in B$. Notice a problem here?

Comment: EDIT: So it dosnt need to pick cases?

Comment: @MarkoPolo I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Nothing nevermind thank you very much! :)